# What is the property in control to be set to get the value from AppResult.Text in Xamarin.UITest?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uitest

I am trying to create custom control in Xamarin.Forms which has the unique id for automation. So, i have set the android renderer's contentDescription property. So, i can get the **AppResult.Label** property to identify the control. But, my requirements is that how to get the control's text property? What property i have to set in control level with the corresponding text to get it in **AppResult.Text** property.

```cs
[Test]
[Description("SampleTest")]
public void WelcomeTextIsDisplayed()
{          
    App.Repl();
    AppResult[] results = App.WaitForElement("myControl");            
    Assert.IsTrue(results[0].Text == "My Control Text", results[0].Text + "\n" + results[0].Description + "\n" + results[0].Id + "\n" + results[0].Label);
}
```

For more information, I have prepared the simple example to explain better about my case. Here, i have derived my custom control from Grid and i introduced the Text property. When i try to view the element using Repl() method, it does not show the Text property but it shows the text properties for Label & Entry controls.

```
<StackLayout >
    <Label Text="Hello, Custom Renderer!" />
    <local:MyEntry Text="In Shared Code" AutomationId="myEntry" />
    <local1:CustomView Text="Sample" BackgroundColor="Red" HeightRequest="500" AutomationId="customControl" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
</StackLayout>
```

```
public class CustomView : Grid
{
    public CustomView()
    {           
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty = BindableProperty.Create("Text", typeof(string), typeof(string),string.Empty);

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }
```

Result while calling App.Repl() ,

[image]

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how different Xamarin.Forms are to Xamarin.Android (which is mostly what my experience is in.)

What happens if you try

> ```
>         app.Query(c => c.Id("NoResourceEntry-2").Property("Text")).SingleOrDefault();
> ```

or some variation of the above? Can you then do something with this? I Hope this helps or points you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use with index position like this:

```
app.Query(c=>c.Id("NoResourceEntry-2"))[0].Text
```

similarly you can use class for same:

```
app.Query(c=>c.Class("LabelRenderer"))[0].Text
```

Query for `Class("LabelRenderer")` gave 2 results. So in above example, you can see it gave you 2 results but you have to use index for particular result.